# Adding labels to percentage stacked barplot ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I am new to ggplot and looking to get some help for a dataset I am making visualizations for.

Here is my current code:

```
#create plot
plot <- ggplot(newDoto, aes(y = pid3lean, weight = weight, fill = factor(Q29_1String, levels = c("Strongly disagree","Somewhat disagree", "Neither agree nor disagree", "Somewhat agree", "Strongly agree")))) + geom_bar(position = "fill", width = .732) 
#fix colors
plot <- plot + scale_fill_manual(values = c("Strongly disagree" = "#7D0000", "Somewhat disagree" = "#D70000","Neither agree nor disagree" = "#C0BEB8", "Somewhat agree" = "#008DCA", "Strongly agree" = "#00405B")) 
#fix grid
plot <- plot + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="29")) + theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + theme(panel.border = element_blank()) + theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) + theme(axis.title.y=element_blank()) + theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()) + theme(axis.text.x=element_blank()) + theme(text=element_text(size=19,  family="serif")) + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color="black")) + theme(legend.position = "top") + theme(legend.text=element_text(size=12)) 
#plot graph
plot
```

This creates this bar chart:
[image]

Right now the problem I am having is trying to add percentage labels on these bars. I want to add text that shows the percentage of each segment, centered and in white letters.

Unfortunately, I have been having some trouble adding geom_text, as it frequently gives me errors because I don't have an x variable and I'm not sure how to fix it, as the way I used fill is sort of peculiar compared to other ways I've seen it done with both x and y variables. I don't really know what I would even add for an x variable considering that the fill is the percentage for each type of response (different response types shown in levels).

Any help would be appreciated! Happy to answer any questions about the dataset if that is important.

Here is an example of what the two relevant columns look like (didn't use head because there's so many variables in this dataset). Basically they show which party a respondent is a part of and if they strongly agree, somewhat agree, etc.

[image: data sample]

Here is the output of dput for the two variables:

```
structure(list(pid3lean = structure(c("Democrats", "Democrats", 
"Democrats", "Democrats", "Independents", "Democrats", "Republicans", 
"Independents", "Republicans", "Democrats", "Democrats", "Independents", 
"Democrats", "Republicans", "Democrats", "Democrats", "Democrats", 
"Democrats", "Democrats", "Republicans"), label = "pid3lean", format.spss = "A13", display_width = 15L), 
    Q29_1String = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Strongly agree", 
    "Somewhat agree", "Neither agree nor disagree", "Somewhat disagree", 
    "Strongly disagree"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(newDoto)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(newDoto, 20))`.

Comment: Please add the data using `dput` to recreate the problem.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Added some sample data - didn't use the command because I believe it would have returned way too many variables (it's a big dataset). Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, but images are not a good way of posting data, try `dput(newDoto[1:20, c("pid3lean", "Q29_1String")]` instead.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I got "Error: unexpected symbol in:
"dput(newDoto[1:20, c("pid3lean", "Q29_1String")]
var"" when I put that

Comment: Then, upload the data to the cloud and provide the link.

Comment: I forgot to close the parenthesis after the last `]`. Just close it `dput(newDoto[1:20, c("pid3lean", "Q29_1String")])`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Ok - I think I added what you wanted to the end of my question - sorry for the confusion! And thank you very much for the help formatting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To put the percentages in the middle of the bars, use `position_fill(vjust = 0.5)` and compute the proportions in the `geom_text`. These proportions are proportions on the total values, not by bar.

```
library(ggplot2)

colors <- c("#00405b", "#008dca", "#c0beb8", "#d70000", "#7d0000")
colors <- setNames(colors, levels(newDoto$Q29_1String))

ggplot(newDoto, aes(pid3lean, fill = Q29_1String)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_fill()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(..count../sum(..count..)*100, "%")),
            stat = "count",
            colour = "white",
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

---

Package `scales` has functions to format the percentages automatically.

```
ggplot(newDoto, aes(pid3lean, fill = Q29_1String)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_fill()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..count../sum(..count..))),
            stat = "count",
            colour = "white",
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

---

## Edit

Following the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70539767/adding-labels-to-percentage-stacked-barplot-ggplot2/70540160?noredirect=1#comment124705758_70540160) asking for proportions by bar, below is a solution computing the proportions with base R only first.

```
tbl <- xtabs(~ pid3lean + Q29_1String, newDoto)
proptbl <- proportions(tbl, margin = "pid3lean")
proptbl <- as.data.frame(proptbl)
proptbl <- proptbl[proptbl$Freq != 0, ]

ggplot(proptbl, aes(pid3lean, Freq, fill = Q29_1String)) +
  geom_col(position = position_fill()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(Freq)),
            colour = "white",
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  coord_flip() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "29")) +
  theme_question_70539767()
```

[image]

---

### Theme to be added to plots

This `theme` is a copy of the theme defined in [TarJae's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70540342/8245406), with minor changes.

```
theme_question_70539767 <- function(){
  theme_bw() %+replace%
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          text = element_text(size = 19, family = "serif"),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black"),
          legend.position = "top",
          legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
          legend.key.size = unit(1, "char")
    )
}
```

Comment: Why not `geom_col`?: geom_col(…)` is `geom_bar(stat = “identity”)`

Comment: @TarJae Even without `aes(y = .)`? I'l check that out. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: @RuiBarradas The problem with this code is that it doesn't calculate the percentages within the column. I would like it so that each column adds to 100%

Comment: @JeaniousSpelur See the edit now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach:

1. Here we do the stats in the dataframe (calculate the percentages and change class to factor of `Q29_1String`
2. using `geom_col`
3. then use `coord_flip`
4. tweak the theme part

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(pid3lean) %>% 
  count(Q29_1String) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(pct = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  mutate(Q29_1String = as.factor(Q29_1String)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = pid3lean, y = pct, fill = Q29_1String)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill", width = .732) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Strongly disagree" = "#7D0000", "Somewhat disagree" = "#D70000","Neither agree nor disagree" = "#C0BEB8", "Somewhat agree" = "#008DCA", "Strongly agree" = "#00405B")) +
  coord_flip()+
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(pct)), 
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5),size=5, color="white",
            ) + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="29")) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x=element_blank(), 
        text=element_text(size=19,  family="serif"), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(color="black"),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.text=element_text(size=12)
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to calculate percentages using `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
newDoto <- newDoto %>% group_by(pid3lean) %>%
  count(Q29_1String) %>%
  mutate(perc = n/sum(n)) %>%
  select(-n)
```

With your existing code, you can just add the following line at the end of your code:

```
plot + 
  geom_text(stat = 'count', aes(label = perc), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), size = 3, color = "white")
```